# Align a Datatable for Jquery in a Div

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatable

I'm having issues aligning a datatable inside of a div. I have a div defined as 50% of the screen and I'd like to put the entire datatable along the right side of the div. Refer to the ascii below as an illustration of what I'd like.

```
__________________________
|  _________________      |
| |                |      |
| |                |      |
| |   This is a    |      |
| |   datatable    |      |
| |                |      |
| |                |      |
| |                |      |
| |                |      |
| |________________|      |
|    This is a div        |
__________________________|

__________________________
|       _________________ |
|      |                | |
|      |                | |
|      |   This is a    | |
|      |   datatable    | |
|      |                | |
|      |                | |
|      |                | |
|      |                | |
|      |________________| |
|    This is a div        |
__________________________|
```

I've tried `text-align: right`, but that results in the information in the datatable being re-aligned, not the whole table. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With Float**

Probably the easiest, though my least favorite, way of doing it, is just applying `float: right;` to your table. This will cause it to float all the way to the edge of the container (paying attention to the padding), and act as an inline element.

The second part of that is important, because that can have some unusual results with nearby text outside of the table.

That being said, as hungerstar pointed out, using a basic [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) will deal with most of the issues with `float`.

**With Inline-Block**

My preferred way is with the `display: inline-block` css attribute for your table. You can essentially do this:

```
<div id="Container">
    <table> <!-- or div with table styles -->
        ...
```

CSS:

```
#Container
{
    text-align: right; /* this effects the actual table */
}

#Container table
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    text-align: left; /* to reset table text */
}
```

Very simply, this mode forces the `table` to act like an inline (text-esque) element, so we can apply the `text-align` attribute to it. The wrapping `#Container` div is merely to keep it from interfering with other nearby elements.

*Why Is This Preferred?*

`float` can sometimes mess up the DOM order and have unexpected results with more complex arrangements, in my experience. It's a perfectly valid approach, but I prefer `inline-block` because it's more predictable.

However, `inline-block` isn't flawless either. For horizontal alignment, multiple `div`s with `inline-block` will have a small space between them (a literal space, caused by the browser treating the element as a text character).

Comment: Floats are easily handled with a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/). Inline-block has a few drawbacks of its own, most notably when horizontal aligning navigation items - i.e. spacing issues like descender heights .

Comment: True. Each has its own advantage and disadvantage. I will update my answer with your information, thanks.

Comment: I first tried the inline-block method that you suggested and it resulted in the misalignment of the headers of the datatable. I then just tried float right and it worked with no issues.

Comment: Yeah, just as @hungerstar said. You sometimes have to clear `inline-table` and `inline-block` to get them to work right too. That's why I provided both solutions :)

Comment: You clear floats not the inline block elements. [Here's some options](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) on how to handle the spacing created by inline-block elements, none are perfect.